# The problem invoke non-displayment of StateVector packaged in qiskit

Tags: qiskit

Here is my source code

```
from qiskit import ClassicalRegister, QuantumRegister, QuantumCircuit, Aer, execute
import qiskit
import numpy as np
import math as m
import scipy as sci
import random
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import permutations
S_simulator = Aer.backends(name='statevector_simulator')[0]

from qiskit.quantum_info import Statevector

def Single_Qubit_Ansatz( qc, qubit, params ):
    qc.ry( params[0], qubit )
    qc.rz( params[1], qubit )
#================================================
q = QuantumRegister( 1)
qc= QuantumCircuit(q)
theta = m.pi/3
phi = 3*m.pi/2



print('___ Initial State ___')
backend = Aer.get_backend('statevector_simulator')
result = qiskit.execute(qc, backend=backend).result()
Statevector(result.get_statevector(qc)).draw('latex')


Single_Qubit_Ansatz(qc, q[0], [theta,phi] )
backend = Aer.get_backend('statevector_simulator')
result = qiskit.execute(qc, backend=backend).result()
Statevector(result.get_statevector(qc)).draw('latex')
```

I don't know why the Statevector won't draw when there are some things like print or code only, so I need to divide them to two block of code, any advises, tks if u can help.

Comment: `from IPython.display import display` Then
`display(my_statevector.draw('latex'))`

Comment: tks, it works 